# Cannot find symbol X_AXIS' in class BoxLayout

Tags: java

I am trying out the BoxLayout manager in Java but I get a compiler error:

> "cannot find symbol X_AXIS"

when I try to set the layout.

Is the problem with my IDE? I am using NetBeans.

```js
package boxlayout;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout.*;

class MainWindow extends JDialog{

    public MainWindow(){
        super(null, "BoxLayout", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        setSize(500,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        createWindow();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createWindow(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));//cannot find symbol X_AXIS
    }
}
public class BoxLayout {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already a class `BoxLayout` in your code, so the compiler tries to find the constant in your class.
Either rename your class (better) or use `javax.swing.BoxLayout.X_AXIS`

Comment: Thank you very much